# python, subprocess library run program one by one

Tags: python-3.x

I need to run a set of bat files one by one. start the new bat file only after the previous one finishes.

```
 subprocess.run("C:/yardi_backup/split_merge/first_parts/{0}.bat".format('PMDOCS_p1'.lower()), check=True)
subprocess.run("C:/yardi_backup/split_merge/first_parts/{0}.bat".format('TOTAL_p1'.lower()), check=True)
```

However, this will start the two bat files at the same time. what should I do to make it right.

Comment: `subprocess.run` should be blocking, i.e., it should wait for command to complete, then return.